# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.template.Configuration

Tags: weblogic12c

When I try to deploy artefact on Weblogic 12c, getting class not found exception. 
I verified freemarker-2.3.20.jar is present in lib folder
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue

Target state: deploy failed on Server AdminServer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.template.Configuration

```
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.report(Jsr88Operation.java:610)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.perform(Deployer.java:140)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:88)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
    at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:74)
    at weblogic.Deployer.mainWithExceptions(Deployer.java:63)
    at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:339)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:184)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```